# How to split Mongoose Connection properly on NestJS

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I want to split my mongoose connection to the single database into two connections (link to the pattern: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections)

The goal I want to achieve is to inject two exact same models that would use different connections.

The way I thought it would work is to register two MongooseModules:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: MongooseConfigFast,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: MongooseConfigSlow,
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Where MongooseConfigFast and MongooseConfigSlow are defined as:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MongooseConfigFast implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
  createMongooseOptions():
    | MongooseModuleOptions
    | Promise<MongooseModuleOptions> {
    return {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      uri: "mongodb://localhost:27017/startup",
      connectionName: ConnectionNames.FAST, // FAST_CONNECTION
    };
  }
}
```

Now in UsersModule I register same schema but providing different names for different connections:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature(
      [
        {
          name: ConnectionNames.USERS_FAST, // Token for fast connection
          schema: UserSchema, // Same User schema
          collection: User.name, // Same User collection
        },
      ],
      ConnectionNames.FAST,
    ),
    MongooseModule.forFeature(
      [
        {
          name: ConnectionNames.USERS_SLOW, // Token for slow connection
          schema: UserSchema, // Same User schema
          collection: User.name, // Same User collection
        },
      ],
      ConnectionNames.SLOW,
    ),
  ],
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UsersController],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

And finally I can inject two models into the UsersService:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  @InjectModel(ConnectionNames.USERS_FAST) // Usign token for fast connection
  private readonly FUserModel: Model<User>;

  @InjectModel(ConnectionNames.USERS_SLOW) // Using token for slow connection
  private readonly SUserModel: Model<User>;

  public async createUser(userInfo: UserInfoDto): Promise<User> {
    return this.SUserModel.create(userInfo);
  }
}
```

When I try to run it, Nest seems to unable to resolve mongoose models registered in UsersModule. Has someone implemented that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue.

Turns out, connectionName property on MongooseModule's options factory is mongoose specific configuration. In order to define a token for Nest DI resolver, I placed connectionName in the MongooseModule config:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: MongooseConfigFast,
      connectionName: ConnectionNames.FAST,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: MongooseConfigSlow,
      connectionName: ConnectionNames.SLOW,
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: How did you manage to read "ConnectionNames" without config service? is that your global variable? or part of config? I want to achieve similar thing where connection uris and connection names are part of config.

Comment: @Chaitanya "ConnectionNames" is just enum with string values:


```export enum ConnectionNames {
  FAST = "fast",
  SLOW = "slow"
}
```